# Text does not change after clicking the buttons - forms, time & global variables

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 sections of javascript code where each should activate changes to text ids following pressing the corresponding buttons. I'm not sure why none of them are working.

Versions 2 & 5 just calls global variables to display
Version 4 just displays a message, where the message depends on the time
Version 7 just takes the value from an input form and displays it

Any ideas of why they are not working? I don't think its the inner.HTML attribute as I have got these to work on other functions. thanks for any help, really appreciate it

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
 height:1000px;
 width:100%;
 background:#fff;
 margin:0;
}

.divider{
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 background:#CCC;
 display:block;
 margin:10px;
}

h2{
 font-size:16px;
 display:block;
}
#confirm-paragraph{}
#global-variable-paragraph{}
#user-input{}
#expressions{}
#elephant-paragraph{}
#method-1{}
#method-2{}
#ml{}
#litres{}
#conditional-operator{}
#cast-1{}
#cast-2{}
```

```html
<!-- Version 2 -->
<section class="divider">
<h2>Global Variable Example</h2>
<button onclick="DisplayAuthorName()">Click Me</button>
<p id="global-variable-paragraph">This text should change after clicking the button.</p>
<p style="color:red; font-weight:bold">NOT WORKING Version 2!!!!!!!!</p>
<script>
var nick = {forename:"Nick", surname:"Smith", age:25, height:null, starsign:undefined}; // object with 5 global variables
function DisplayAuthorName() {
 document.getElementById("global-variable-paragraph").innerHTML = forename + " " + surname + " is " + age;
}
</script>
</section>



<!-- Version 4 -->
<section class="divider">
<h2>Expressions Example</h2>
<button onclick="timeFunction()">Click Me</button>
<p id="expressions">This text should change after clicking the button.</p>
<p style="color:red; font-weight:bold">NOT WORKING Version4!!!!!!!!</p>
<script>
function timeFunction() {
 var time = new Date().getHours();
 var message;
 if (hour < 12) {
  message = "Good Morning.";
 } else if (12 < hour < 18) {
  message = "Good Afternoon.";
 } else {
  message = "Good Evening.";
 }
 document.getElementById("expressions").innerHTML = message;
}
</script>
</section>



<!-- Version 5 -->
<section class="divider">
<h2>Methods Example</h2>
<button onclick="UseMethods()">Click Me</button>
<p class="method-1">This should change to uppercase, and should display the forename global variable.</p>
<p class="method-2">This should change to a string and display the variable age.</p>
<p style="color:red; font-weight:bold">NOT WORKING Version5!!!!!!!!</p>
<p>Unable to call global variables?</p>
<script>
function UseMethods() {
document.getElementById("method-1").innerHTML = nick.forename.toUpperCase();
document.getElementById("method-2").innerHTML = nick.age.toString();
}
</script>
</section>



<!-- Version 7 -->
<section class="divider">
<h2>Conditional Operator Example</h2>
<p>Enter a number:</p>
<input id="inputtest">
<button onclick="ConditionalOperatorFunction()">Click Me</button>
<p id="conditional-operator">This text should change when entering a number and clicking the button.</p>
<p style="color:red; font-weight:bold">NOT WORKING Version7!!!!!!!!</p>
<script>
function ConditionalOperatorFunction(){
 var testnumber, largeorsmall;
 testnumber = document.getElementById("inputtest").value;
 largeorsmall = (inputnumber < 50) ? "This is a small number in my opinion!":"This is a large number in my opinion!";
 document.getElementById("conditional-operator").innerHTML = largeorsmall;
}
</script>
</section>
```

Comment: you are using variable `forename`, check how it is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You are not accessing the variables correctly in version 2
  use `nick.forename` etc.
- **hour** is not defined in version 4
- version 7 , you have class to the element and accessing through id. No!

*Note:* Please check the errors in your code and try.
     It's pretty much straightforward, check the errors in the console and update.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
 height:1000px;
 width:100%;
 background:#fff;
 margin:0;
}

.divider{
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 background:#CCC;
 display:block;
 margin:10px;
}

h2{
 font-size:16px;
 display:block;
}
#confirm-paragraph{}
#global-variable-paragraph{}
#user-input{}
#expressions{}
#elephant-paragraph{}
#method-1{}
#method-2{}
#ml{}
#litres{}
#conditional-operator{}
#cast-1{}
#cast-2{}
```

```html
<!-- Version 2 -->
<section class="divider">
<h2>Global Variable Example</h2>
<button onclick="DisplayAuthorName()">Click Me</button>
<p id="global-variable-paragraph">This text should change after clicking the button.</p>
<p style="color:red; font-weight:bold">NOT WORKING Version 2!!!!!!!!</p>
<script>
var nick = {forename:"Nick", surname:"Smith", age:25, height:null, starsign:undefined}; // object with 5 global variables
function DisplayAuthorName() {
 document.getElementById("global-variable-paragraph").innerHTML = nick.forename + " " + nick.surname + " is " + nick.age;
}
</script>
</section>



<!-- Version 4 -->
<section class="divider">
<h2>Expressions Example</h2>
<button onclick="timeFunction()">Click Me</button>
<p id="expressions">This text should change after clicking the button.</p>
<p style="color:red; font-weight:bold">NOT WORKING Version4!!!!!!!!</p>
<script>
function timeFunction() {
 var hour = new Date().getHours();
 var message;
 if (hour < 12) {
  message = "Good Morning.";
 } else if (12 < hour < 18) {
  message = "Good Afternoon.";
 } else {
  message = "Good Evening.";
 }
 document.getElementById("expressions").innerHTML = message;
}
</script>
</section>



<!-- Version 5 -->
<section class="divider">
<h2>Methods Example</h2>
<button onclick="UseMethods()">Click Me</button>
<p id="method-1">This should change to uppercase, and should display the forename global variable.</p>
<p id="method-2">This should change to a string and display the variable age.</p>
<p style="color:red; font-weight:bold">NOT WORKING Version5!!!!!!!!</p>
<p>Unable to call global variables?</p>
<script>
function UseMethods() {
document.getElementById("method-1").innerHTML = nick.forename.toUpperCase();
document.getElementById("method-2").innerHTML = nick.age.toString();
}
</script>
</section>



<!-- Version 7 -->
<section class="divider">
<h2>Conditional Operator Example</h2>
<p>Enter a number:</p>
<input id="inputtest">
<button onclick="ConditionalOperatorFunction()">Click Me</button>
<p id="conditional-operator">This text should change when entering a number and clicking the button.</p>
<p style="color:red; font-weight:bold">NOT WORKING Version7!!!!!!!!</p>
<script>
function ConditionalOperatorFunction(number){
 var largeorsmall;
  inputnumber = document.getElementById("inputtest").value;
 largeorsmall = (inputnumber < 50) ? "This is a small number in my opinion!":"This is a large number in my opinion!";
 document.getElementById("conditional-operator").innerHTML = largeorsmall;
}
</script>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks! Quick question though that I noticed - the code does not work if the variable 'inputnumber' is changed to 'testnumber' - why?

Comment: also it works by changing ConditionalOperatorFunction(number) to ConditionalOperatorFunction()

Comment: In that case you have to supply the value of `number` to your js code.

Comment: ok so I assume ConditionalOperatorFunction(number) defines the variable as a number whereas ConditionalOperatorFunction() doesn't, right?

Comment: In this case `number` is a parameter for the function that you can use in your function. So, technically *Yes*.

Answer (score 1):

## Version 2:

`forename` is a property of `nick`. To use forename, you have to write `nick.forename`.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/wiridofini/edit?html,js,output)

```
function DisplayAuthorName() {
    document.getElementById("global-variable-paragraph").innerHTML
        = nick.forename + " " + nick.surname + " is " + nick.age;
}
```

You should write your code in a proper js file. A decent editor will fix this kind of error.

## Version 4:

Replace `time` with `hour`.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/wiridofini/edit?html,js,output)

```
function timeFunction() {
    var hour = new Date().getHours();
    var message;
    if (hour < 12) {
        message = "Good Morning.";
    } else if (12 < hour < 18) {
        message = "Good Afternoon.";
    } else {
        message = "Good Evening.";
    }
    document.getElementById("expressions").innerHTML = message;
}
```

## Version 5:

You select nothing. Use `document.querySelector`, it is far easier.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/wiridofini/edit?html,js,output)

```
function UseMethods() {
    document.querySelector(".method-1").innerHTML = nick.forename.toUpperCase();
    document.querySelector(".method-2").innerHTML = nick.age.toString();
}
```